# Add values with curl inside a fileupload in a multipart form

Tags: curl, file-upload, console

**My Goal**

I try to automatically change some file on an embedded device over ethernet. To do this, I am creating a batch file to use on my computer which uses curl to send the POST for fileupload.

**My Problem**

Sadly I need some special values inside the "File-Part" of the multipart form. (name=uploadfile & filename=index.htm) I know how to add more values to the multipart form, but I don't know how to add a value to the "File-Part" which is capsulated in the multipart form

**My question**

How can I add more information/values to the "File-Part" of an multipart form with curl? Is it even possible with curl from a batchfile?

This is how the Request should look like:

```
POST /cgi-bin/fs_fileupload.cgi HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.1.72
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:45.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/45.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
DNT: 1
Referer: http://192.168.1.72/files.html
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 21930
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------86458141819368430751619760852

-----------------------------86458141819368430751619760852
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadfile"; filename="index.htm"
Content-Type: text/html

<html>
...
...
</html>

-----------------------------86458141819368430751619760852
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="path"

/
-----------------------------86458141819368430751619760852
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"

upload
-----------------------------86458141819368430751619760852--
```

My embedded system needs those entries inside the "File-Part":

> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadfile"; filename="index.htm"
>   Content-Type: text/html

**My Tries**

***set as global multiform value:***

> curl -v -X POST -H "Expect:" -F "file=@index.htm;" -F path=/ -F submit=upload http://url/cgi-bin/fs_fileupload.cgi --trace-ascii /dev/stdout

This works from the curl side. I see the Values added to the POST on the Multipart Form level.

```
== Info:   Trying 192.168.1.72...
== Info: TCP_NODELAY set
== Info: Connected to 192.168.1.72 (192.168.1.72) port 80 (#0)
=> Send header, 211 bytes (0xd3)
0000: POST /cgi-bin/fs_fileupload.cgi HTTP/1.1
002a: Host: 192.168.1.72
003e: User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
0057: Accept: */*
0064: Content-Length: 22084
007b: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------
00bb: ----18bc7d9c1cff49ca
00d1: 
=> Send data, 153 bytes (0x99)
0000: --------------------------18bc7d9c1cff49ca
002c: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="index.htm
006c: "
006f: Content-Type: application/octet-stream
0097:
=> Send data, 16384 bytes (0x4000)
0000: <html>
...
...
13de: </html>
=> Send data, 452 bytes (0x1c4)
0000:
0002: --------------------------18bc7d9c1cff49ca
002e: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="name"
005b:
005d: uploadfile
0069: --------------------------18bc7d9c1cff49ca
0095: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"
00c6:
00c8: index.htm
00d3: --------------------------18bc7d9c1cff49ca
00ff: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="path"
012c:
012e: /
0131: --------------------------18bc7d9c1cff49ca
015d: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"
018c:
018e: upload
0196: --------------------------18bc7d9c1cff49ca--
```

But I need the values inside the "File-Part", because of the embedded system on the other side. When I do it like that, I end up with a file with the name index.htm and with the content index.htm except the real content! This is because of the Fileupload implementation on the Embedded device. And I don't have the possibility to cahnge that.

***set inside file values:***

> curl -v -X POST -H "Expect:" -F "file=@index.htm;name=uploadfile;filename=index.htm" -F path=/ -F submit=upload http://%url%/cgi-bin/fs_fileupload.cgi --trace-ascii /dev/stdout

This gives me a warning from the curl side. And it also does not work on the embedded system side, because the needed values are missing.

```
Warning: skip unknown form field: name=uploadfile
```

More output

```
== Info:   Trying 192.168.1.72...
== Info: TCP_NODELAY set
== Info: Connected to 192.168.1.72 (192.168.1.72) port 80 (#0)
=> Send header, 211 bytes (0xd3)
0000: POST /cgi-bin/fs_fileupload.cgi HTTP/1.1
002a: Host: 192.168.1.72
003e: User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
0057: Accept: */*
0064: Content-Length: 21875
007b: Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--------------------
00bb: ----07d21aa34b954425
00d1:
=> Send data, 153 bytes (0x99)
0000: --------------------------07d21aa34b954425
002c: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="index.htm
006c: "
006f: Content-Type: application/octet-stream
0097:
=> Send data, 16384 bytes (0x4000)
0000: <html>
...
...
13de: </html>
=> Send data, 243 bytes (0xf3)
0000:
0002: --------------------------07d21aa34b954425
002e: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="path"
005b:
005d: /
0060: --------------------------07d21aa34b954425    
008c: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="submit"
00bb:
00bd: upload
00c5: --------------------------07d21aa34b954425--
== Info: Recv failure: Connection was reset
== Info: stopped the pause stream!
== Info: Closing connection 0
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection was reset
```

This doesn't work. Curl tells me, it can not recognize my entered value. It doesn't work ether on the embedded side. The connection gets reseted because of the missing values!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I found out a simple solution. I'm not sure why I didn't done it that way in the first place...

> curl -X POST -H "Expect:" -F "uploadfile=@path/index.htm;filename=index.htm;" -F path=/ -F submit=upload http://%url%/cgi-bin/fs_fileupload.cgi

with that upload the multipart form data looks as expected

```
=> Send data, 159 bytes (0x9f)
0000: --------------------------5621ade8c7849eac
002c: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploadfile"; filename="ind
006c: ex.htm"
0075: Content-Type: application/octet-stream
009d:
=> Send data, 16384 bytes (0x4000)
0000: <html>
```